# Pynput keyboard

Tags: python, pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

s_key = input(str(" What leter do you want : "))

keyboard.press(s_key)
keyboard.release(s_key)
```

when I run this it gives me an error but when I replace `s_key` with let's say `Key.cmd` (for a windows key) it works but if I type `Key.cmd` where it asks it gives me an error. I think this is because say I typed `key.cmd` where it asks it wraps it in quotes so it look like this:

```
keyboard.press("Key.cmd")
keyboard.release("Key.cmd")
```

I have looked at it and I've come to the conclusion that when you have a variable like that it wraps it in quotes and I don't think `pynput.keyboard` registers the special keys in quotes:

```
keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

try:
    s_key = getattr(Key, input("What letter do you want : ")) # get the key
except AttributeError:
    print("no such key %s " % s_key) # if the key is not valid, notify the user about it
else: # if key is valid
    keyboard.press(s_key)
    keyboard.release(s_key)
```

You have to type in `cmd` instead of `Key.cmd`, because if you type in `Key.cmd`, this code tries to use `Key.Key.cmd`, which, of course, will not work !

Comment: im not sure if im stupid but why do I get this error https://pasteboard.co/JOF1O1E.png

Comment: Thanks il try to see if it works when I get home also you said cmd instead of key.cmd when I tried key.cmd it worked but I might be wrong in this case 